# Two plural forms for acronyms

Tags: formatting, acronyms

Is it possible to have more than one plural form for acronyms?

I want to use the following german term for revision/version control system:

VVS for **Versionsverwaltungssystem**

the normal plural would be **Versionsverwaltungssysteme**

But I would also use it like this:
...mit verteilten **Versionsverwaltungssystemen** (n at the end)

How may I do that right with latex? :)

Comment: Sure, that would be my workaround/fix if it's not (AFAIK it is not) supported by the `acronym` package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I’d recommend taking a look at the [`glossaries`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) package. When defining an acronym you have six user-defined keys at your disposal which you can use for storing any additional information. Minimal example:

```
%% Document generation:
%% $ pdflatex example && makeglossaries example && pdflatex example

\documentclass[naustrian]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
  longplural={Versionsverwaltungssysteme},
  user1={Versionsverwaltungssystems},
  user2={Versionsverwaltungssystemen}
]{VVS}{VVS}{Versionsverwaltungssystem}

\let\acrlonggen\glsuseri
\let\acrlongpldat\glsuserii

\begin{document}

\noindent
das \acrlong{VVS}      \\
des \acrlonggen{VVS}   \\
die \acrlongpl{VVS}    \\
den \acrlongpldat{VVS}

\printglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]